# Combining Files in R while keeping the filenames associated with each row

Tags: r

I'm looking to combine several hundred csv files into a single file using R. With each row, I would like the original file name it came from to be displayed in the new file.

Thank you in advance!

Using the following code, I can combine the files but don't know which file each row came from:

```
`library(data.table)
setwd("E:/test5/12-2/results")
files <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
temp <- lapply(files, fread, sep=",")
data <- rbindlist(temp)
write.csv(data, file="results.csv")`
```

Comment: `my_txt_csv <- function(x) {
    out <- fread(x)
    out <- out %>% mutate(across(everything(),as.character))
    cbind(Site=x,out)
  }
  df1 <- lapply(files,my_txt_csv) %>% bind_rows()`

Comment: Was in the middle of posting that when the question was closed. That should be what you are looking for.